# Interferometry: effect of aspheric lens on self-mixing effect

Tags: optics, reflection, lenses, interferometry, photonics

I want to perform [self-mixing interferometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-mixing_laser_interferometry) experiments using a laser diode, as was done [here](https://youtu.be/MUdro-6u2Zg). I'm going to use a low-power laser diode. However, I want to improve the performance of the device, including for longer range use, by using an [aspheric lens](https://www.edmundoptics.com.au/knowledge-center/application-notes/optics/all-about-aspheric-lenses/) (a common collimation optic). [It is stated](https://www.thorlabs.com/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_id=3811) that an option for aspheric lenses is to use antireflective coating. But since the self-mixing effect requires light to be reflected back into the LD cavity for detection by the integrated photodiode, I wonder if this antireflective coating will somehow work against the self-mixing effect. Furthermore, I also wonder whether just the aspheric lens on its own (without any coating) will have a negative effect on the self-mixing effect (by having some effect on the light being reflected and passing back through towards the LD). (1) Will the antireflective coating work against the self-mixing effect at all? (2) Will the aspheric lens on its own (without any coating) have a negative effect on the self-mixing effect at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An aspheric lens with antireflection coating is a good choice. This optic would ideally focus your (monochromatic) laser beam onto the surface under study (SUS). You do not want reflections from the focusing optic, only the SUS, thus antireflection coating is a good choice. You want the light to be well-focused onto the SUS, thus an aspheric curvature is a good choice.

The question of how much better the AR-coated aspheric lens is compared to a non-coated spherical lens, however, depends on the details. If your budget is $\infty$, then spring for the fancy lens. If not, do a cost-benefit analysis.